# >What's the smallest prime number that doesn't divide the number $x= 9+9^2+9^3+.....9^{2010}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> What's the smallest prime number that doesn't divide the number  $$x= 9+9^2+9^3+.....9^{2010}?$$

Clearly  $x $ is divisible by  $2 ,3 ; 5 $

Since it's divisible by $10$ and $3$

But how can I test the other prime numbers ?

Comment: One way is to write the sum a bit simpler. Hint: what is $9x-x$?

Comment: @Arthur  = $9^{2011} -9$

Comment: @Arthur  is the answer  $17$

Comment: @prayersmith.. yes!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a very good approach though but this should work:

As quoted by @Arthur in his comment, $9x-x=8(x)=9({9^{2010}-1})$

Now notice that $9^1-1,9^2-1,9^3-1,9^5-1,9^6-1,9^{10}-1,9^{12}-1,9^{18}-1,9^{30}-1,19^{67}-1$ all divide $9^{2010}-1$ as $(2,3,5,67)$ are prime factors of $2010$.

Now recall the Fermat little theorem :

> $p|a^{p-1}-1$ if $p$ is prime.

So we have $2,3,7,1,13,19$ divide $9^{2010}-1$. Additionally we can prove that $5|9^{2010}-1$ as $9\equiv-1\pmod 5\implies 9^{2010}\equiv1\pmod5$.

Now we are left with $17$, if we find that $17|9^{2010}-1$ too. Then we will have do work a bot more (Luckily not in this case !!).

Claim: $17$ does not divide $9^{2010}-1$.

> Proof: $9\equiv-8\pmod{17}\implies 9^{2010}\equiv(-8)^{2010}\equiv(64)^{1005}\equiv(-4)^{1005}\equiv(-4)(16)^{502}\equiv(-4)(-1)^{512}\equiv-4\pmod{17}$.

Actually I made some silly mistakes $(9^{12}-1,9^{18}-1$ does not divide $9^{2010}-1)$, thanks for @Barry Cipra for pointing them out.

The case $9^{12}-1|9^{2010}-1$ gave us that $13|9^{2010}-1$ and $9^{18}-1|9^{2010}-1$ gave us that $19|9^{2010}-1$. Note that the latter is of no significance as it won't affect the result and we can prove the former using another method.

We already know that $9^6-1|9^{2010}-1$ and hence $(3^2)^6-1=3^{12}-1|9^{2010}-1 \implies 13|9^{2010}-1$

Comment: According to WA, $9^{12}-1$ and $9^{18}-1$ do not divide $9^{2010}-1$.  However $3^{12}-1=9^6-1$ does, which is enough to take care of $p=13$.  WA also says that $19$ does not divide $9^{2010}-1$, but that doesn't change your result.